# Bulding a simple calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a simple calculator. The problem is that when I press a button it doesn't show on the display.

```js
var loadPage = function() { //using on load on the body of the html
  var one = document.getElementById("1"); //geting the id of the numbers
  one.addEventListener("1", clickListener, false);
  var two = document.getElementById("2");
  two.addEventListener("2", clickListener, false);
  var three = document.getElementById("3");
  three.addEventListener("3", clickListener, false);
  //and so on until 9
};

function clickListener(e) //a click listener for the numbers
{

  var value = document.getElementById("calculator__display");
  if (e.type == "1")
    value.innerHTML = e;
  if (e.type == "2")
    value.innerHTML = e;
  if (e.type == "3")
    value.innerHTML = e;
  //and so on until 9
}
```

```html
<!doctype html5>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Calculator.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="Calculator.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="loadPage()">

  <div class="calculator__display">0</div>

  <div class="operation_keys">
    <button class="key--operator" id="add">+</button>//the operation buttons
    <button class="key--operator" id="subtract">-</button>
    <button class="key--operator" id="multiply">x</button>
    <button class="key--operator" id="divide">÷</button>
  </div>
  <div class="number_keys">//the numbers
    <button id="7">7</button>// 7,8,9
    <button id="8">8</button>
    <button id="9">9</button>
    <button class="key--equal" id="calculate">=</button>//the equal button
    <button id="4">4</button>
    <button id="5">5</button>
    <button id="6">6</button>
    <button id="1">1</button>
    <button id="2">2</button>
    <button id="3">3</button>
    <button id="0">0</button>
    <button id="decimal">.</button>//the decimal point
    <button id="clear">AC</button>//the reset button

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

When I click the button, I want the number to be displayed. I do not understand why the number is not being displayed. Does anyone have any advice or can help me understand what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: i changed it to getElmentByClassName("calculator__display") and changed the id to charchters and still dosn't work

Comment: There is no `getElmentByClassName` in javascript.

Comment: var value= document.getElementsByClassName("calculator__display");

Comment: @loay HTML Comments follow the form `<!-- comment -->` not `// comment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using "document.getElementById" when the element has no id.

Either you need to change 
  **div class="calculator__display">0**
To
  **div id="calculator__display">0**

or change 
  **document.getElementById("calculator__display");**
To
  **document.getElementsByClassName("example");**

--UPDATE--

Along with changing the selector above there were a couple of more problems.

- your "addEventListener" functions are expecting "click" to be their first parameter but you were passing "1"
- also inside your clickListiner function you were using the variable e which is the event variable from the click event. You actually need to be using the variable "this" which is the button that got clicked.

```js
var loadPage = function() { //using on load on the body of the html
  var one = document.getElementById("1"); //geting the id of the numbers
  one.addEventListener("click", clickListener, false);
  var two = document.getElementById("2");
  two.addEventListener("click", clickListener, false);
  var three = document.getElementById("3");
  three.addEventListener("click", clickListener, false);
  //and so on until 9
};

function clickListener(e) //a click listener for the numbers
{

  var value = document.getElementById("calculator__display");
  if (this.id == "1")
    value.innerHTML = this.textContent || this.innerText;
  if (this.id == "2")
    value.innerHTML = this.textContent || this.innerText;
  if (this.id == "3")
    value.innerHTML = this.textContent || this.innerText;
  //and so on until 9
}
```

```html
<body onload="loadPage()">

  <div id="calculator__display">0</div>

  <div class="operation_keys">
    <button class="key--operator" id="add">+</button>
    <button class="key--operator" id="subtract">-</button>
    <button class="key--operator" id="multiply">x</button>
    <button class="key--operator" id="divide">÷</button>
  </div>
  <div class="number_keys">
    <button id="7">7</button>
    <button id="8">8</button>
    <button id="9">9</button>
    <button class="key--equal" id="calculate">=</button>
    <button id="4">4</button>
    <button id="5">5</button>
    <button id="6">6</button>
    <button id="1">1</button>
    <button id="2">2</button>
    <button id="3">3</button>
    <button id="0">0</button>
    <button id="decimal">.</button>
    <button id="clear">AC</button>

  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: i changed it to document.getElementsByClassName("calculator__display"); and still it dosn't work @Cody Fortenberry

Comment: @loay you actually had a few more errors. I added a code snippet using your code with the updated changes.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few issue in your code:

- The first parameter expected by `addEventListener` is the name of an
  event. You should be passing `"click"`, not `"1"`, `"2"` etc.
- `calculator__display` is a class, not an id.
  `document.getElementById("calculator__display");` will not work
  unless you add an id to the element.
- `e.type` is the event type triggered by the event listener, not a custom parameter as you are using
  it.
- IDs can not start with a number (though it will work in most browsers).

---

I am using a loop to add the event listeners. This removes a lot of your repeated code.
I have added a custom data attribute to the buttons that holds the numeric value of the button.

Hopefully this will give you enough ideas to work on the rest of your calculator.

```js
var loadPage = function() {
  var numberKeys = document.getElementsByClassName('number_keys');

  for (let i=0;i<numberKeys.length;i++) {
    numberKeys[i].addEventListener('click', clickListenerNumber, false);
  }
  
  var operationKeys = document.getElementsByClassName('operation_keys');
  
  for (let i=0;i<operationKeys.length;i++) {
    operationKeys[i].addEventListener('click', clickListenerOperation, false);
  }
};

function clickListenerNumber(e) {
  var value = document.getElementById("calculator__display");
  value.innerHTML = e.target.getAttribute('data-value');
}

function clickListenerOperation(e) {
  /* TODO
  * Handle operation button click
  */
}
```

```css
#calculator__display {
  background: yellow;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body onload="loadPage()">

  <div id="calculator__display">0</div>

  <div class="operation_keys">
    <button class="key--operator" id="add">+</button>
    <button class="key--operator" id="subtract">-</button>
    <button class="key--operator" id="multiply">x</button>
    <button class="key--operator" id="divide">÷</button>
  </div>
  <div class="number_keys">
    <button id="seven" data-value="7">7</button>
    <button id="eight" data-value="8">8</button>
    <button id="nine" data-value="9">9</button>
    <button class="key--equal" id="calculate">=</button>
    <button id="four" data-value="4">4</button>
    <button id="five" data-value="5">5</button>
    <button id="six" data-value="6">6</button>
    <button id="one" data-value="1">1</button>
    <button id="two" data-value="2">2</button>
    <button id="three" data-value="3">3</button>
    <button id="zero" data-value="0">0</button>
    <button id="decimal">.</button>
    <button id="clear">AC</button>

  </div>


</body>
```

There are some obvious problems that this code does not attempt fix, for example, you are replacing the display value every time a number is clicked. How would you enter the value "100"?